# "My Places" Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

Is there any api available to allow me to access the "My Places" maps directly? I am looking to both: update existing maps and create new ones from a client application. I have been unable to find anything currently.

Answer (score 1):

No? The only method that I can find is for reading map data by appending `&output=[format]` to an existing map's URL, e.g.:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&msid=[].[]&output=kml
```

or:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&msid=[].[]&output=json
```

This, obviously, doesn't provide the update or create functionality you're looking for.

Related: [Google Maps output=kml broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680872/google-maps-output-kml-broken)