# Android Maps - showing two or more paths within a single mapview

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I want to show 2 or more paths between 2 locations similar to "Suggested Routes" in Google Maps.
I am able to draw 1 path through this link [J2ME Map Route Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations/2023685#2023685) . 
Now i want to show 2 paths simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://csie-tw.blogspot.in/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html) worked perfectly for me. i called the method twice in main activity and the new overlay din`t replace the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the J2ME Map Route Provider, you just need to change/remove this line of code:

```
 Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
  public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
   TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
   textView.setText(mRoad.mName + " " + mRoad.mDescription);
   MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(mRoad, mapView);
   List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
```

### listOfOverlays.clear();

```
   listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
   mapView.invalidate();
  };
 };
```

You don't want to clear the map with each new overlay, just add it to the existing set of overlays.

Comment: I`ve removed "listOfOverlays.clear();" but still previous overlays gets replaced by the new