# What parameters to choose in GPS tracing for requestLocationUpdates?

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager

I am making an application for GPS tracking. I create LocationManager and set requestLocationUpdates.

```
LocationManager myManager = (LocationManager) mMap.getSystemService("location");
myManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, this);
```

How to select the optimal parameters MIN_TIME and MIN_DISTANCE for the battery and recording the normal track? Please, give me reason for the answer.

Thanks in advance!

**UPD:** I need the optimal parameters. How to detect the location, I know!

Comment: what kind of application are you developing? MIN_TIME and MIN_DISTANCE can be calculated based on your requirement

Comment: GPS tracking and recording your way. My requirement is minimum electricity consumption with maximum accuracy, as it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListner);
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

Comment: also give the permissions in manifest file....INTERNET,ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS,ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION,CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES

Comment: If to specify MIN_TIME=0 and MIN_DISTANCE=0, as you, notifications will be obtained as frequently as possible. I want to know what options to select the most optimal for the electricity consumption

Comment: Criteria myCriteria = new Criteria();
myCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
myCriteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
// let Android select the right location provider for you
String myProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(myCriteria, true); 

// finally require updates at -at least- the desired rate
long minTimeMillis = 600000; // 600,000 milliseconds make 10 minutes
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(myProvider,minTimeMillis,0,locationListener);

Comment: go with the code which i gave u now it will help you out i think this is the solution u are finding of

Comment: Notifications will be obtained as once at 10 minutes?

Comment: minTime :  the minimum time interval for notifications, in milliseconds. This field is only used as a hint to conserve power, and actual time between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value.

Comment: minDistance : the minimum distance interval for notifications, in meters

Comment: I know it! I want record my way, using GPS. What is the path I write it down, if GPS is updated every 10 minutes? I need the normal parameters for energy conservation and for the record paths.

Comment: do you want to draw the path or what ?

Comment: see i havent done this but this link might be helpful to you please see it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations/2023685#2023685