# j2memaprouteprovider project is not working,  gives me a force close

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, java-me, android-maps

There was a [question about drawing lines in google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2023669) and one of the solutions suggested is a complete project which is found on the following link.

http://code.google.com/p/j2memaprouteprovider/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FJ2MEMapRouteAndroidEx%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fci%2Fgeo%2Froute%253Fstate%253Dclosed

I just downloaded this application and it is not working. The whole thing, It gives me a force close.

I expected it to work without changes, as it was posted in above link. What possible things I could do in order to let it work?

Also, I didn't get the idea of the URL, I mean parsing?

Comment: what exactly _is not working_?

Comment: The whole thing, It give me a force close. I thought it should work since it was posted in that place :S:S but it is not working.. what possible things I could do in order to let it work ...

Comment: It did not raise any exception? There is no log file you could look into?