# Check if user not following the route in Android Google Maps

Tags: android, gps, maps, routes

I am working an application where user need to develop turn by turn navigation.
I have developed this by using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations/11880407#11880407)

Now this gives me route and very good turn by turn navigation. 
But my question is suppose if the user has missed the turn and he takes other turn then how would I come to know that user is not on the path specified?

Need help in this regard.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey! @kendrelaxman, Have you got solution for your  problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The directions gives you the whole distance of the route, you can check if this distance is increasing, this means he is going on the wrong route which is also not so efficient solution but I can't see any other way to do it unless **Google** provides directions & navigation in `Android Google Maps SDK`.

Comment: distance solution is not efficient as I have tried it. It does not give the accurate distance also if the user takes parellel road path then this scenario fails. :-(

Comment: Yea I know, because I tried to do same as what you need, couldn't accomplish it.

Comment: So what do you think could be possible solution to this?

Comment: Do you have to do this inside your application? because I think you can do a request for Navigation App from Google (Note that Navigation doesn't work on all countries) and let the user opens Navigation App from your App and their it is full Navigation. Other than this, you will have to wait for Google to provide more ability for the Developer to do this.