# How to draw shortest path between two locations

Tags: android, google-maps

**How can I show shortest path in my code like it is in the picture?**
[image]

I'm using this code to find shortest distance between two points.

```
Location locationA = new Location("point A");

locationA.setLatitude(lat);
locationA.setLongitude(long);

Location locationB = new Location("point B");

locationB.setLatitude(lat);
locationB.setLongitude(long);

distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

Comment: [Possible duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2023669/1050058)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance you're calculating with `Location` is essentially 'as the crow flies'.  That's the distance it takes to get from A to B traveling through the air.  In the picture you noted, it appears you want the shorting *driving* distance from A to B, in which case you want navigation with roads, interstates, etc.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations) post is similar; it addresses the possibility of getting driving directions.

Comment: Google doesnt provide KML support anymore, I get the solution nonetheless. Thanks.