# google map with route in blackberry

Tags: java, google-maps, blackberry, blackberry-storm, blackberry-maps

how to use google map with route in blackberry . i tried blackberry map with route but in my device (Storm 2) cant display map .  i dont know what is the issue ?

any one have idea ragarding google map in blackberry application  than let me know.

i tried this `http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=23.4444,72.44445&daddr=23.55555,72.55555`
and open this url in BB browser but it cant redirect to map site .

how can we handle google map or blackberry map with route in BB application ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have implemented Google Map with route in Blackberry via Google Map Installed App.

```
   public void invokeGoogleMap() { 
     int mh = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("GoogleMaps");
     if (mh == 0) 
     {
          try 
          {
            throw new ApplicationManagerException("GoogleMaps isn't installed");
          } 
          catch (ApplicationManagerException e) 
          {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          }
          UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              stubDialog.inform("GoogleMaps isn't installed on your device.download it from m.google.com/maps.");
            }
          });
     }
     else
     {
         URLEncodedPostData uepd = new URLEncodedPostData(null, false);
         uepd.append("action", "ROUT"); // or LOCN
         uepd.append("start", "23.039568,72.566005");
         uepd.append("end", "23.02,73.07");
         String[] args = { "http://gmm/x?" + uepd.toString() };
         ApplicationDescriptor ad = CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(mh)[0];
         ApplicationDescriptor ad2 = new ApplicationDescriptor(ad, args);
         try
         {
             ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().runApplication(ad2, true);
         } 
         catch (ApplicationManagerException e) 
         {
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
         }

     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Blackberry browser is not fully functional for java script to display route info in browser field.Instead you have to use Blackberry maps. for this the following link will help you.

[How to find the route between two places in BlackBerry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542252/how-to-find-the-route-between-two-places-in-blackberry)

Comment: Thanx ..i m used this <location-document><GetRoute><location lon='-8052237' lat='4346518' label='Kitchener, ON' description='Kitchener, Ontario, Canada' /><location lon='-7569792' lat='4542349' label='Ottawa, ON' description='Ottawa, Ontario, Canada' /></GetRoute></location-document> and i got error "Unable to calculat route"

Comment: see below link  http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Blackberry-Maps-Unable-to-calculate-route/td-p/940559#M150588