# android url to access KML route

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

I am trying to draw path between two points on google map using url below,

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=13.005621,77.577531&daddr=13.005621,77.579531&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml

before it was working properly, but now it shows exception,

```
 I/System.out(461): Unexpected end of document
```

doc is returning null why?
my code is bellow,

http://pastebin.com/XvR0rYdQ

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These links help u to code for maps:

[MAPS Tutor](http://www.anddev.org/route_-_improved_google_driving_directions-t1892.html)
[Maps Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542252/how-to-find-the-route-between-two-places-in-blackberry)

[Maps Api](http://csie-tw.blogspot.com/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html)

If u want url only then use this :
 http://code.google.com/apis/kml/

 These Is complete source code for maps location .

### Android

[Android G1 screenshot http://img249.imageshack.us/img249/3336/androidmaproute.jpg](http://img249.imageshack.us/img249/3336/androidmaproute.jpg)

```
public class MapRouteActivity extends MapActivity {    
 LinearLayout linearLayout;
 MapView mapView;
 private Road mRoad;    
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
  mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);    
  new Thread() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    double fromLat = 49.85, fromLon = 24.016667; 
    double toLat = 50.45, toLon = 30.523333;
    String url = RoadProvider
      .getUrl(fromLat, fromLon, toLat, toLon);
    InputStream is = getConnection(url);
    mRoad = RoadProvider.getRoute(is);
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
   }
  }.start();
 }

 Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
  public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
   TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
   textView.setText(mRoad.mName + " " + mRoad.mDescription);
   MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(mRoad, mapView);
   List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
   listOfOverlays.clear();
   listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
   mapView.invalidate();
  };
 };

 private InputStream getConnection(String url) {
  InputStream is = null;
  try {
   URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
   is = conn.getInputStream();
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return is;
 }    
 @Override
 protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
  return false;
 }
}
```

See full code on [J2MEMapRouteAndroidEx](http://code.google.com/p/j2memaprouteprovider/source/browse/#svn/trunk/J2MEMapRouteAndroidEx) on Google Code

Comment: I added complete in my answer n join on my facebook for any discussion :)

Comment: I too belongs to bangalore itself :)

Comment: String url = RoadProvider
      .getUrl(fromLat, fromLon, toLat, toLon);
here RoadProvider?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6079/discussion-between-rizvan-and-jyosna)