# Display route in android

Tags: android, android-maps

I am using following example  [source code](http://code.google.com/p/j2memaprouteprovider/source/browse/trunk/J2MEMapRouteAndroidEx/#J2MEMapRouteAndroidEx%253Fstate%253Dclosed)  but I can't get long distance route in map. It only works for small distance on map.
Is there are any limitation to access map?

If some one has better idea please help.

Comment: make use of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612524/android-url-to-access-kml-route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete source code at https://github.com/frogermcs/RoutePathExample for how to draw path between two geolocation. I use this code without any trouble at all. You should check it

Answer (score 0):

Make use of this [secret Google API](http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?output=js&oe=utf8&q=from%3a%7B%22Surey,London) and Android Map API to show the distance between two points.

Comment: thanks for replay but can you guide how to use your given secret Google API with Android map API , mainly i want to show route between two point as well also want to  show some other nearby point with this route.

But following code(My one ) not useful in long distance location.

Comment: this is the same code i am using it's not work properly for long distance like between Delhi to Mumbai :(

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code and it is working fine, even if I put two points in two different countries. I believe you are not implementing it in the right way, because this code is retrieving the KML provided by Google for the two points you choose, which always returns a route unless the two points are in different continents and there is no route for going by car.

I suggest you show us how did you use the code in your app.